# Can I turn pages in ebook with single touch?

Tags: ipad, ui, ebook

I am considering the purchase of the iPad2 and among other things, the one that bother me is this -- you can turn pages when reading an ebook with hand gesture, i.e. moving finger from left to right with nice animation. This is cool for starter.

But I want something 100% traditional -- just touch of the finger on left or right edge of the screen, and I would get just next/previous page. No animation, no moving hand.

Is this possible on iPad? If yes -- is it device settings, or given app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is. At least in the iBooks app (the one from Apple). I don't know about the Kindle app, but I'm pretty sure it's possible as well.

You can make a single touch in the right or left part of the screen to go to the next or previous page in your eBook.

Comment: Great. One point more for iPad purchase ;-) Thank you.

Comment: Kindle has the same one touch page turning. Instapaper also has a great reading interface with one touch page turning or article scrolling. You'll love the iPad.